# Meteor.User does not load with all fields on initial load

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I have added an additional field on Meteor.Users collection called usertype. In Iron-router I am returning the user object if user is logged in. Now in my template I need to check if this usertype field is present else, I direct the user to user registrations screen.

What is happening here is that even though I have the usertype field in my publish function, the user object is not returned with this field initially. It only shows up after 2-3 object loads. And this confuses the template loading logic, as this field is not found on initial load, but when infact the field is present.

```
DashboardController = RouteController.extend({
template: 'dashboard',
subscriptions: function() {
    this.userProfileSub = Meteor.subscribe('singleUser', this.myId());
},
myId: function() {
    var userId = Meteor.userId();

    if(!userId)
        { userId = ''; }

    return userId;
},
user: function() {
    return Meteor.users.findOne(this.myId());
},
data: function() {
    var user = this.user();
    console.log(user);

    if(user)
    {
        return {
            user: this.user(),
            ready: this.userProfileSub,
        };          
    }
}
});
```

Here is the publish method:

```
Meteor.publish('singleUser', function(id) {
check(id, String);
return Meteor.users.find({_id:id}, {fields: { emails: 1,
                                            profile: 1,
                                            usertype: 1,
                                            "services.facebook.id": 1,
                                            "services.facebook.email": 1,
                                            "services.twitter.screenName": 1,
                                            "services.twitter.profile_image_url": 1,
                                            "services.google.email": 1,
                                            "services.google.picture": 1}});
});
```

**EDIT**
As answer given below, if the subscription is moved inside the waitOn block it should wait for the subscription to load completely.

```
waitOn: function() {
    this.userProfileSub = Meteor.subscribe('singleUser', this.myId());
    return [this.userProfileSub];
},
```

But now when I try to wait for multiple subscriptions to load in the wait array, it apparently is not waiting for all of them. I still get empty array. Even though I check in the action block. I can find the data later from my console.

```
waitOn: function() {
    return [
            Meteor.subscribe('singleUser', this.myId()), 
            Meteor.subscribe('singleAgentByUserId', this.myId()), 
            Meteor.subscribe('singleClientByUserId', this.myId())];
},

action: function () {
    // this.ready() is true if all items returned from waitOn are ready
    if (this.ready())
    {
        this.render();
    }
    else
        this.render('Loading');
},
```

Comment: can you post your publish method too? =)

Comment: @ahren added the publish method

Answer (score 0):

Update **EDITED** (See revision history for much different version due to original question)

Try:

```
waitOn: function() {
    return [
        Meteor.subscribe('singleUser', Meteor.userId()), 
        Meteor.subscribe('singleAgentByUserId', Meteor.userId()), 
        Meteor.subscribe('singleClientByUserId', Meteor.userId()];
},
loadingTemplate: "loading",
action: function () {
    this.render('dashboard');
}
```

Comment: Thanks this seems to work. But using this example I am trying to subscribe to multiple collections, but the waitOn does not wait for all of them to finish.

Comment: @srinivas waitOn should wait for each of them, I placed an array operator `[xx]` for this reason, put each `Meteor.subscribe` that you may have in there.

Comment: I have done exactly that, but it does not wait, even though I am checking for that in action block. Updating my question above to show that.

Comment: @srinivas try using `Meteor.userId()` directly instead of `this.myId()`

Comment: I tried that,  but its not working. I can't understand where it could go wrong as it should be quite straightforward. Also it's also not loading reactively, even though I can find it in console.

Comment: @srinivas Have you defined a loading template?

Comment: Yes that is defined on the router configuration itself.

Comment: @srinivas I mean have you defined a loading template in terms of html, i.e `<template name="loading">xxx</template>`. Case/capitalization also matters.

Comment: @srinivas I dont think i can think of anything else that's wrong. If its not working as expected try filing a bug request at github.com/EventedMind/iron-router